# Ruby on Rails: How to POST in my API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, api, http-post

I'm trying to create a task, but the attributes are null

Mi controller:

```
#app/controllers/api/v1/tasks_controller.rb
def create
   respond_with Task.create(params[:Task])
end
```

I tried do POST to localhost:3000/api/v1/tasks with this data:

`{"task": {"name":"hello world"}}`  or `{"name":"hello world"}`

but the result has attributes null:

```
#Response Body
{
   "id": 1,
   "name": null,
   "created_at": "2014-03-23T22:41:37.961Z",
   "updated_at": "2014-03-23T22:41:37.961Z"
}
```

**Update:**

```
# Server log
Started POST "/api/v1/tasks" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-23 17:03:03 -0600
Processing by Api::V1::TasksController#create as JSON
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "tasks" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)  [["created_at", Sun, 23 Mar 2014 23:03:03 UTC +00:00], ["updated_at", Sun, 23 Mar 2014 23:03:03 UTC +00:00]]
   (153.5ms)  commit transaction
Completed 201 Created in 159ms (Views: 0.6ms | ActiveRecord: 154.0ms)
```

Comment: Could it be the upcased symbol in `params[:Task]`, instead of `params[:task]`?

Comment: Thanks @vee. I changed to lowercase, but the problem continues

Comment: Do the server logs give any clues?  Have you checked the generated insert query?  Is the `name` properly inserted in the database?

Comment: Can you show how you are posting to this url? and can you show the params in your rails log after it calls api/v1/tasks?

Comment: Can you debug the code and inspect if you are receiving something on params[:task]? Maybe params[:task] or params[:Task] returns nothing... and it would not be a problem with json... but with your submit

Comment: The insert query shows that `params[:Task]` returned `nil`.  I want to say the problem is definitely retrieval of `task` from the `params` hash.  `params["task"]` should work.  Another option would be to do `params.deep_symbolize_keys!` before `params[:task]`.

Comment: Seems like your params are either blank OR if you are in production mode they may not be logged.  Are you posting with an outside app, javascript/coffeescript, or some other method?  Try adding a logger.debug params in the create method of the controller as well.

Comment: Could you update your question to show how are you sending this post request?

Comment: Thank you my friends! I resolved the problem with your help (and I updated my post).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks vee, emcanes, Carlos Figueiredo and BroiSatse for your answers. I solved the problem.

I changed create action:

```
#app/controllers/api/v1/tasks_controller.rb
def create
   respond_with Task.create(task_params)
end
```

And I added:

```
#app/controllers/api/v1/tasks_controller.rb
private
...
def task_params
  params.require(:task).permit(:name)
end
```